# android ViewPager swipe both direction

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to swipe view pager in both direction with infinite rotations.
For example 
When swipe right then 1->2->3->1->2. So on
When swipe left then 1->3->2->1->3. So on

Comment: You can take reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668588/infinite-scrolling-image-viewpager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library maybe help you

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager:library:1.0.0'
}
```

In your layout

```
<com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

In your code, wrap your existing PagerAdapter with the InfinitePagerAdapter

```
PagerAdapter wrappedAdapter = new InfinitePagerAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setAdapter(wrappedAdapter);
```

But this library just working when you have at least 4 pages. More info [link github library](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager)

Comment: Thank you for help.