# Access a ViewPager Fragment's public method from the main Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main Activity which XML holds a `RelativeLayout` with a `ViewPager`:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
```

Then I have a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to manage the `Fragment`.

Now I have a public method on the `Fragment` called `getFoo()` (which obviously returns foo).

Question: What is the correct way to get the `Fragment`'s `foo` from the main Activity?

I tried using `addOnPageChangeListener()` on the `ViewPager`, but then I'm not able to get the active instance of the `Fragment`.

Comment: "Tried to use addOnPageChangeListener on the ViewPager, but then - unable to get active instance of the Fragment" - If you have passed list of fragments to your viewpager adapter, you can retrieve Fragment on index in onPageChanged()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` much like having your own `ArrayAdapter`.

Hold a `List<Fragment>` in that (passed through the constructor), then just use `adapter.getItem(position).getFoo()`

Very minimal example.

```
public MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    public int getCount() { return fragments.size(); }
    public Fragment getItem(int position) { return fragments.get(position); }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct approach, I think. I was using this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html where things defined a bit different, but your approach is the one I am moving away with now.

Comment: That guide recreates a fragment everytime you slide to it. This answer provides the ability to "save the state" of all the Fragments

Comment: Yes. I want the app to create list of seven slides (for the days of the week). So user can slide between them. If user goes "outside" week range - the slides will be destroyed and another 7 slides created. The data for each group will be saved/fetched from the database.

Comment: There are better ways to handle making a continuing ViewPager  than destroying and adding more.

Comment: Can you tell please, in a few words - what is the better way? I will search for more info on it myself then.

Comment: Something like an infinite viewpager. Add the 7 fragments once, you can keep scrolling. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668588/infinite-scrolling-image-viewpager